# how to use LTP (Linux test Project) for Linux kernel testing on real hardware?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have linux based embedded device where I need to test LTP but the problem is there are not enough space that I can push opt/ltp/ folder there and run the tesecases.

is there any other way that I can use that one or is there possible to run single scripts into it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to solve this issue by applying a external memory support to the hardware. After that, I have configure whole ltp setup into it and succeeded to run all individual scripts.